# Scroll down to clicked DIV not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Does anyone know why this isn't working properly? Basically you should have a list of links with unique anchors and by clicking on one of the links the page should scroll down to the div containing the link and give the containing div a golden border while removing all the old gold borders? I can't figure out what's wrong with my code :)

```js
$('.anchor').click(function(e) {

  //remove all previous borders
  $('.anchor *').css('border', '');

  //element ID
  var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');

  // prevent
  e.preventDefault();

  // top position relative to the document
  var pos = id.offset().top;
  var pos = pos - 100;

  // animated top scrolling
  $('body, html').animate({
    scrollTop: pos
  });

  //gold border for clicked div.
  $(this).parent().css("border", "1px solid gold");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container' id='".$anchor."'>
  <a class="anchor" href="#'.$anchor.'">
    <h4>Title</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you see the error? `id.offset is not a function`. `id` is a string. You probably wants to call `offset()` on a jQuery element. Isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `var pos = id.offset().top;` is problematic and also 2 times you've declared `var pos`.

If you're using `jQuery` use `$` to address any element like `$(id)` instead of mere `id`

```
$('.anchor').click(function(e) {

  //remove all previous borders
  $('.anchor *').css('border', '');

  // prevent
  e.preventDefault();

  // top position relative to the document
  var pos =  $(this).parent().offset().top;
  pos = pos - 100;

  // animated top scrolling
  $('body, html').animate({
    scrollTop: pos
  });

  //gold border for clicked div.
  $(this).parent().css("border", "1px solid gold");
})

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container' id='".$anchor."'>
  <a class="anchor" href="#'.$anchor.'">
    <h4>Title</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the offset of an attribute, which does not have it. You need to get an offset of the element.

When doing that:

`var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');`

You'll get the id (`string`) back.

So when you have the id, you need to get the element, then you can request the offset.

```
var myElement = $(id);
myElement.offset();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/78254/)

Change like below:

```
  var $this = $(this); // DOM Object
  var pos = $this.offset().top;
  var pos = pos - 100;
```